# Getting error "only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC" while sending HSM signed transaction

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, coinbase

I am using **Bison trials** ropsten RPC `(https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.ethereum.bison.run)` to send the Google HSM signed transaction, but for some reason this fails with the below error -

> only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC

I tried the functionality using infura RPC `(https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxx)` and that works well.

I am sharing some code snippet below -

```js
const send = async () => {
    let { ethAddress, chksumAddress } = await createWalletViaHSM();
    let ethAddrHash = ethutil.keccak(Buffer.from(ethAddress));
    let sig = await findEthereumSig(ethAddrHash);
    let recoveredPubAddr = findRightKey(ethAddrHash, sig.r, sig.s, ethAddress);

    const tx1 = myContract.methods.transfer(account2, web3.utils.toWei('10', 'ether'))
    const txParams = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex((await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(ethAddress, 'pending'))),
        to: ADDRESS,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(await web3.eth.getGasPrice()),
        gas: web3.utils.toHex(await tx1.estimateGas({ from: ethAddress })),
        chainId: web3.utils.toHex('3'),
        data: tx1.encodeABI(),
        r: sig.r.toBuffer(),
        s: sig.s.toBuffer(),
        v: recoveredPubAddr.v
    }

    const tx = new Tx(txParams, { chain: 'ropsten' });

    /** START: Signing transaction with google HSM service */
    let txHash = tx.hash(false);
    sig = await findEthereumSig(txHash);
    recoveredPubAddr = findRightKey(txHash, sig.r, sig.s, ethAddress);
    tx.r = sig.r.toBuffer();
    tx.s = sig.s.toBuffer();
    tx.v = new BN(recoveredPubAddr.v).toBuffer();
    /** END: Signing transaction with google HSM service */

    // Send signed tx to ethereum network
    const serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx)
        .on('transactionHash', (data) => console.log('transactionHash', data))
        .on('error', error => console.log(error));
}
```

I referred similar questions on stack-overflow and people suggested to add chainId, which I already have added.

Comment: did you solve this issue? currently i am facing same issue